# Github not showing my team as contributers

Tags: git, github

my team (which consist of me, member A and member B) and I are new to github and I have created a repo and have added them as collaborators through the repo settings. I had them push sample txt files (with random words, such as 'foobar') to their own forks and make pull request to my fork. I then merged the pull request to my own repo, but my repo is only listing me as the sole contributer.

Member A and member B's files are now on my repo, but my repo still says 1 contributor and when I click on that link it only shows me and Member B contributions.

Comment: How did you perform the merge? Did you squash?

Comment: They made a pull request through the github site and I merged the pull request. I'm not sure what squash means but I did not use that.

Comment: Is the repo private? If not, could you please post a link to it?

Comment: No, it is public. Here is the link. [github repo](https://github.com/Mohammadhunan97/pipe_channel)

Comment: According to the repository history the following users have contributed: Mohammadhunan97, mariasilla (these two are github users), Kristyn Ginski (this one is not linked to a github user). What is the question here exactly?

Comment: On the github repo you can see it says "1 contributer" to the right [see](http://imgur.com/dHRpGyW)

Comment: This information is not very important and I imagine that it is not processed in real time by github. I think you should wait to see it updated (because your commits are all from today...). The real important information is the git commit history...

Comment: @Philippe is right. Right now it says 2 contributors, previously it said 1.

Comment: @Mkr just in case you are not aware (you said you are new to git): the standard workflow is not to fork the repository, but for all the collaborators to work in the same repo. When a collaborator wants to develop a feature, they create a new branch from master, commit the code and open a new pull request from their branch back to master.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for the GitHub API to list contributors](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-contributors) has this to say:

> Contributors data is cached for performance reasons. This endpoint may return information that is a few hours old.

The page https://github.com/Mohammadhunan97/pipe_channel/graphs/contributors without the historical graph corresponds to the API output of https://api.github.com/repos/Mohammadhunan97/pipe_channel/contributors .

By adding the argument `anon=1` you can also include users that don't have their commit author emails linked to a GitHub user: https://api.github.com/repos/Mohammadhunan97/pipe_channel/contributors?anon=1

By looking at https://github.com/Mohammadhunan97/pipe_channel/commit/9ac4ae1e163562ade676f33e0ad7ad2b08adb31e.patch (I just added `.patch` to the end of a link to a commit) one of the contributors didn't use their correct email address. For how to fix this see the [GitHub documentation on how to fix when commits are not linked to any user](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/#commits-are-not-linked-to-any-user).